# Batch file Authentication failed when running in C#

Tags: c#, .net, git, powershell, batch-file

I am new to world of PowerShell script and trying to Clone from git repo.

I have calling a PowerShell script from a .bat(batch).
While calling .bat file from C# I am getting below error.

If I run .bat file alone from my local drive working fine.
I would like to make this .bat file call from C#.

[image: Error message while cloning]

Comment: Its GIT authentication issue, it its not an issue with C#

Comment: can you update your question with more details